# Проблема в полёте пуль

Tags: c#, unity3d

делаю небольшой шутер для двух игроков, каждый может стрелять.
Проблема заключается в том, что когда пуля летит с большой скоростью, то в её траектории есть некие  зоны, в которых она не касается объекта, и соответственно `OnTriggerEnter2d` там не работает

Вот скрипт полёта пули:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public int Player;
    public float speed= 0.4f;
    public Vector3 mode; //Направление пули (Vector3.left, right)
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        rb.velocity = mode * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1umk.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не помогло.

Comment: используй  для имитации  стрельбы   лучи — raycasting

Comment: или  бросание  лучей   еще  называется

Comment: и  память  поэкономишь,  так  как  пули  создавать  не  надо,    и   производительность  повысить  можна. но  только  при  грамотном  использовании   метода

Comment: @Slavik может ему принципиально видеть саму пулю

Comment: @Methorn нуу  да ,  пулю   конечно  не  видать  будет

Comment: @Methorn  но  в  принципе  можно  сделать   и  чтобы  было  видно

Comment: @Methorn   например   создать   какуюто  линию  с  хвостом,  и  нехай  она  летит    несколько  кадров

Comment: @Methorn    ну  типо  понял  как  получится,  пуля  на  самом  деле  уже  попала,  но  всё  ещё  летит  ))

Comment: @Slavik это не чатик. постарайся писать одним комментарием

Comment: Пули в шутерах не надо делать. Там надо использовать Raycast и всего лишь создать анимацию пули.

Answer (score 0):

AAA шутеров с баллистикой типа **Battlefield** по пальцам пересчитать, так делать не надо.
**Fortnite**, **Overwatch** и **Call of Duty** (кроме снайперок) и т.д. и т.п. стреляют рейкастами и это называют `hitscan projectiles`!
Трассировка пуль в них лишь визуальная декорация.

Гуглить нужно `hitscan unity`, материалов завались.